# About "equality" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why does the code

```
km=KMeans(n_clusters=3)
y = km.fit_predict(MyDataFrame)
km.cluster_centers_
```

works, but the code

```
y = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(MyDataFrame)
KMeans(n_clusters=3).cluster_centers_
```

doesn't?!

What's the difference?

What is behind the equality `km=KMeans(n_clusters=3)` ??

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "does't works".

Comment: It gives following error: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'. @JanChristophTerasa

Comment: Apparently `fit_predict` modifies the state of `km`, creating the attribute in the process.

Comment: I believe neither of the two answers rightly answer the question, but @JanChristophTerasa 's comment does.

Comment: @Ayush apparently, looking at the accepted answer, the question really was "what does the operator `=` do in Python?". Sometimes I really cannot believe the kind of questions asked here.

Comment: perhaps, but I think the question deserves a closer look. In both cases, the cluster_centers_ attribute was being accessed, of an object on whom KMeans() had been called and had supposedly nothing to do with fit_predict(). I'm not sure how the answers address any of that, but well..

Comment: Then why doesn't `fit_predict` do the same thing in second code of question? (creating the attribute, as you said) @JanChristophTerasa

Comment: Because you are not accessinh an existing instance, but a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an equality, but an assignment. The first line generates an object of type KMeans and assigns it to km. Now km represents exactly this object and it can be modified in the next lines. In the second version you generate a new object of type KMeans both times so you work with different objects.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `KMeans(n_clusters=3)` on two lines are 2 different instances.

While in the first example, there's only one `KMeans` instance `km`.